# Problem with chemmacros, beamer and filehook-scrlfile.sty

Tags: beamer, koma-script, chemmacros, filehook

I am using `chemmacros` with `beamer` and it produces the following error

> 2017/08/28 basic chemmacros module
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
>   Package: scrlfile 2019/10/12 v3.27 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
>   LaTeX Warning: Command \InputIfFileExists has changed.
>   Check if current package is valid.
>   LaTeX Warning: Command \InputIfFileExists has changed.
>   Check if current package is valid.
>   ) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook-scrlfile.sty
>   Package: filehook-scrlfile 2011/01/03 v0.1 filehook patch for scrlfile package
>   ! Package filehook Error: Detected 'scrlfile' package with unknown definition o
>   f \InputIfFileExists.
>   Use the 'force' option of 'filehook' to overwrite it..
>   See the filehook package documentation for explanation.
>   Type H  for immediate help.

If I comment out `chemmacros` or use a different documentclass to `beamer` there is no error.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

While I do get a usable output it is disconcerting to see an error coming up in the compilation and I am not sure if it will cause a fatal output in different usage of `chemmacros` . Is this a bug in `KOMA-script` as I believe it was recently updated but `chemmacros` wasn't.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\begin{document}

Test

\end{document}
```

Comment: According to my TexLiveUtility I have the latest `filehook` package Version v0.6 – 2019/10/03. The included filehook-scrlfile.sty is version 2011/01/03 v0.1 but '\RequirePackage{filehook}` which is indeed the latest version.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik This happens with the newest filehook version 0.6 from ctan

Comment: Your suggestion of `\PassOptionsToPackage{force}{filehook}` removes the error, so it is a workaround. Thank you. I had tried `chemmacros` with `scrartcl`, `scrbook` etc and no problem with it, so must just be a `beamer` problem

Comment: Actually, the problem is with `filehook-scrlfile` (a `filehook` patch to the `scrlfile` package). Unfortunately there's no update to that yet... Try adding \PassOptionsToPackage{force}{filehook} before \documentclass{beamer}. I'm not sure if all funcitonalities of `scrlfile` will be preserved though...

Comment: @Leeser (I ammended my last comment) The problem is actually caused by loading `filehook` and then `scrlfile`. `beamer` loads the former and then `chemmacros` loads the latter.

Comment: `scrlfile` got updated as reaction to changes in the LaTeX kernel; now `filehook-scrlfile` probably has to be updated, too

Comment: @clemens should package author (Martin schaerrer) be informed or does he automagically get informed ?

Comment: @Leeser well, there are https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/filehook/issues/1 and https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/filehook/issues/3 so I think he knows

Comment: With the newest version of sansmathaccent the problem should be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been resolved by an update of the sansmathaccent package. It now no longer uses the `filehook` package.

Comment: Sorry for the huge delay: I released a fix for `filehook` yesterday.

Answer (score 12):

The issue has been fixed in the last `filehook` update. An update to your LaTeX installation should resolve the issue. (Additionally, as [Ulrike wrote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/526677/48973), `sansmathaccent` had already been changed not to use `filehook`, which removed this particular incompatibility.)

---

As noted in the comments, the problem is that `filehook-scrlfile` has not been updated to work with the new definition of `\InputIfFileExists` in `scrlfile`. Until the author updates this file accordingly, as a workaround, you can place a file called `filehook-scrlfile.sty` with the following content in your compilation directory.

```
%% Modified version of filehook-scrlfile as a workaround.
%% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515183/48973.
%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{filehook-scrlfile}[2011/01/03 v0.1 filehook patch for scrlfile package]
\RequirePackage{filehook}
\begingroup
\long\def\scrlfile@InputIfFileExists#1#2{%
  \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\ifx\csname #1-@alias\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
    \scr@replacefile@msg{\csname #1-@alias\endcsname}{#1}%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi
  {%
    \expandafter\InputIfFileExists\expandafter{\csname
      #1-@alias\endcsname}{#2}%
  }%
  {\IfFileExists{#1}{%
      \expandafter\scr@input@withhook\expandafter{\@filef@und}{#1}{#2}%
    }}%
}
\long\def\filehook@scrlfile@InputIfFileExists#1#2{%
  \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\ifx\csname #1-@alias\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
    \scr@replacefile@msg{\csname #1-@alias\endcsname}{#1}%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi
  {%
    \expandafter\InputIfFileExists\expandafter{\csname
      #1-@alias\endcsname}{#2}%
  }%
  {\IfFileExists{#1}{%
      \expandafter\filehook@swap
      \expandafter{\@filef@und}%
      {\scr@load@hook{before}{#1}%
      #2\@addtofilelist{#1}%
      \filehook@every@atbegin{#1}%
      \filehook@atbegin{#1}%
      \@@input}%
      \filehook@atend{#1}%
      \filehook@every@atend{#1}%
      \scr@load@hook{after}{#1}%
    }}%
}
\long\def\filehook@@scrlfile@InputIfFileExists#1#2{%
  \let\InputIfFileExists\filehook@InputIfFileExists
  \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\ifx\csname #1-@alias\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
    \scr@replacefile@msg{\csname #1-@alias\endcsname}{#1}%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi
  {%
    \expandafter\InputIfFileExists\expandafter{\csname
      #1-@alias\endcsname}{#2}%
  }%
  {\IfFileExists{#1}{%
      \expandafter\filehook@swap
      \expandafter{\@filef@und}%
      {\scr@load@hook{before}{#1}%
      #2\@addtofilelist{#1}%
      \filehook@atbegin{#1}%
      \@@input}%
      \filehook@atend{#1}%
      \scr@load@hook{after}{#1}%
    }}%
}
\ifcase
    \expandafter\ifx\csname InputIfFileExists \endcsname\latex@InputIfFileExists 0\else
    \expandafter\ifx\csname InputIfFileExists \endcsname\scrlfile@InputIfFileExists 0\else
     1%
    \fi\fi
\relax
  \global\let\filehook@InputIfFileExists\filehook@scrlfile@InputIfFileExists
  \global\let\filehook@@InputIfFileExists\filehook@@scrlfile@InputIfFileExists
  \global\expandafter\let\csname InputIfFileExists \endcsname\filehook@InputIfFileExists
  \PackageInfo{filehook}{Package 'scrlfile' detected and compensated for}%
\else
  \iffilehook@force
    \global\let\filehook@InputIfFileExists\filehook@default@InputIfFileExists
    \global\let\filehook@@InputIfFileExists\filehook@@default@InputIfFileExists
    \global\expandafter\let\csname InputIfFileExists \endcsname\filehook@InputIfFileExists
    \PackageWarning{filehook}{Detected 'scrlfile' package with unknown definition of \string\InputIfFileExists.^^J%
                              The 'force' option of 'filehook' is in effect. Macro is overwritten with default!}%
  \else
    \show\InputIfFileExists
    \expandafter\show\csname InputIfFileExists \endcsname
    \show\scrlfile@InputIfFileExists
    \PackageError{filehook}{Detected 'scrlfile' package with unknown definition of \string\InputIfFileExists.^^J%
                            Use the 'force' option of 'filehook' to overwrite it.}{}%
  \fi
\fi
\endgroup
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `filehook-scrlfile.sty'.
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped for me!

Comment: doesn't work for me, is there a way not to use this package?

Comment: Of course. Just don't use it. If you have a different problem, consider writing a new, elaborate question.

Comment: Update the filehook-scrlfile.sty with the above filehook-scrlfile.sty code. The directory location is ..........\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\filehook

Comment: @J4cK MiKTeX will "repair" the file on the next update, so this is not a very safe solution. If you don't like having to put the file in the same directory while the bug persists, you can create a user texmf tree, which will be safe from being modified by MiKTeX.

Answer (score 5):

I am on a Windows 10 system using TeXstudio. I updated MiKTeX 2.9 on 1/9/2020 and still have the filehook error. By using the `\PassOptionsToPackage{force}{filehook}` command in my preamble, my `\include` commands are working again. I hope this may help someone.