# filehook error with memoir after update texlive 2019 in Oct 15

Tags: luatex, memoir, unicode-math, xsim, filehook

After the new `LaTeX2e <2019-10-01>` version, I got this error:

> ! Package filehook Error: Detected 'scrlfile' package with unknown
>   definition o f \InputIfFileExists.

It seems related with some definition in KOMA Script, as described [here](https://texwelt.de/fragen/25524/warnung-command-inputiffileexists-has-changed). As instructed I updated Koma from their repository:

> tlmgr install --reinstall --repository
>   https://www.komascript.de/repository/texlive/2019 koma-script

But the error persists.

Does somebody knows if there is another package to be updated after the recent changes in `LaTeX2e`?

EDIT: MWE Added, with the command suggested by @PhelypeOleinik

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{force}{filehook} 
\documentclass[ebook]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\usepackage{xsim}
\begin{document}    
   Test 
\end{document}
```

EDIT2,Oct 22,2019: Added the code suggested by @PhelypeOleinik in the Answer:

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\load@onefilewithoptions
{\expandafter\let\csname\@currname.\@currext-h@@k\endcsname\@empty
    \let\CurrentOption\@empty% Anchor point to make sure we're patching     the right place
}{}{}{\errmessage{This patch is no longer necessary}%
    \newcommand\gobblesix[6]{}\gobblesix}
\patchcmd\load@onefilewithoptions
{\InputIfFileExists}
{\expandafter\let\csname\@currname.\@currext-h@@k\endcsname\@empty
    \InputIfFileExists}{}{\FAILED}
\makeatother
\PassOptionsToPackage{force}{filehook}
\documentclass[ebook]{memoir}
\usepackage{filehook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{xsim}
\begin{document}
    Test
\end{document}
```

I got this error:

```
Package filehook Warning: Detected 'scrlfile' package with unknown definition of
 \InputIfFileExists.
The 'force' option of 'filehook' is in effect. Macro is overwritten with    default
! on input line 108.
```

Comment: I use memoir package, maybe there is some inconsistency here, found in `log`: `(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty
Package: filehook 2019/10/03 v0.6 Hooks for input files`
`(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook-memoir.sty
Package: filehook-memoir 2011/01/03 v0.1 filehook patch for memoir class
Package filehook Info: Detected 'memoir' class: the memoir hooks will be moved t
o the `At...OfFiles' hooks on input line 42.
))`

Comment: Maybe related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/512189. Please add a short minimal working example. Why do you load both packages `filehook` and `scrlfile`?

Comment: Both `scrlfile` and `filehook` were updated to match the LaTeX kernel update in which `\InputIfFileExists` was changed. However `filehook-scrlfile` (which is part of `filehook`) wasn't yet updated to account for the  `scrlfile` update. It's the same problem as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/512189/134574) and the workaround, meanwhile `filehook` isn't updated again, is to use `\PassOptionsToPackage{force}{filehook}`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I just used `\PassOptionsToPackage{force}{filehook}` before, and then after \documentclass, got this `lualatex-math.sty` error: `! LaTeX Error: Unknown option 'force' for package 'filehook'.`

Comment: @tatojo The error message is odd, but that command should come before loading the `filehook` package, so you can put this before the `\documentclass`. After `\begin{document}` will have no effect. Try this and tell if it worked, please.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, first I tried the command before the `\documentclass`, got the error I mentioned!

Comment: @tatojo Then please post a minimal example. In the question I linked this workaround worked, so it is something particular to your case.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, just edited the question and added a MWE.

Comment: Why is this labeled koma script if you are using memoir?

Comment: @daleif Looking at it now, I managed to narrow down the issue to `\documentclass{memoir} \usepackage[force]{filehook}`. With any other class the `force` option works. Does `memoir` do anything to inhibit that option?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik it probably adds its own hooks, memoir hooks into several of these. I'll have a look tomorrow, feel free to have a look in the memoir source

Comment: @daleif Thanks! What is weird is that the option is reported as unknown... I'll see what I can find out.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik probably because it makes assumptions on how it is defined

Comment: @tatojo Something simpler, if you don't use `random selection` of `xsim`, compile using `xelatex`. It doesn't fix the problem, but you will avoid loading `lulatex-math` (which loads `filehook`), until it is updated.

Comment: Since both the MWE and the answer don't mention KOMA-Script, but deal with `memoit` and `filehook` instead, I edited your title and tags accordingly. Feel free to roll back if you disagree, but please make the link to KOMA-Script clearer in that case.

Comment: Please tell me if I'm wrong,: I labeled '`koma`' because this row in `log` file: `Package: scrlfile 2019/10/12 v3.27 KOMA-Script package (loading files)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update 2020-02-04:** both `memoir` and `filehook` were updated and now this problem shouldn't happen. If it does, please update your TeX distribution.

---

Here you have two problems at once. The first one was reported [here](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/198), and is due to a bad timing of setting package hooks. This happens because `filehook` loads `filehook-memoir`, and `filehook-memoir` does `\RequirePackage{filehook}`, and this makes the option parser go off tracks and report that `filehook` doesn't have a `force` option (even though it does).

The issue has already been fixed [here](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/92acad48601d19d4be320fb64dde29a5868934c9) and will eventually be updated in the LaTeX format. For now, use this patch (this has to be the very first thing in your document):

```latex
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\load@onefilewithoptions
  {\expandafter\let\csname\@currname.\@currext-h@@k\endcsname\@empty
   \let\CurrentOption\@empty% Anchor point to make sure we're patching the right place
  }{}{}{\errmessage{This patch is no longer necessary}%
        \newcommand\gobblesix[6]{}\gobblesix}
\patchcmd\load@onefilewithoptions
  {\InputIfFileExists}
  {\expandafter\let\csname\@currname.\@currext-h@@k\endcsname\@empty
   \InputIfFileExists}{}{\FAILED}
\makeatother
```

After you get that out of the way, just tell `filehook` to use the `force` option until `memoir` is updated (should be soon) and `filehook-memoir` is updated to match the updated `memoir`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{force}{filehook}
```

---

By the way, the problem doesn't depend on `xsim` and `fontspec`, also the problem arises with `unicode-math` because it eventually loads `filehook`, so the issue can be narrowed down to:

```latex
\PassOptionsToPackage{force}{filehook}
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{filehook}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem with `xsim` boils down to a conflict between ` filehook` and `scrlfile`. Or rather the fact, that `filehook-scrlfile` didn't get an update, yet...

Comment: @clemens Yes, apparently only the main `filehook` got an update, and the patches to specific class/packages did not, like [`scrlfile`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/512189/134574), as you say, and `memoir`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, got errors, please take a look to the new MWE.

Comment: @tatojo It's not an error, it's a warning. Although it's usually a bad idea to ignore those, there's not much you can do until both `memoir` (Lars is already working on this one) and `filehook` are updated. You'll have to wait or update local copies of the packages.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik has filehook been updated. Including the memoir support file? Just wanted to test it before releasing an updated memoir

Comment: @daleif `filehook` yes, `filehook-memoir` not yet (neither `filehook-scrlfile`, that I know of).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, @daleif: Any news about the expected updates: `filehook-memoir` and `filehook-scrifile`?

Comment: @tatojo ask the maintainer (I maintain `memoir` not `filehook-memoir`)

Answer (score 0):

Although not a final answer, what allowed me to continue working, and compiling  was to place the files `filehook.sty`, `filehook-scrlfile.sty` and `filehook-memoir.sty`  @SergioCallegari posted [here](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/filehook/issues/4/filehook-needs-more-updating-to-deal-with), in `texmf-local/tex/latex/filehook/` and refresh the TeX database.

Comment: I published an update to filehook now, so this workaround is no longer needed.

Comment: @MartinScharrer, Well, it looks like everything's okay now. Nice work!

Comment: Thanks. Good to get some feedback.