# Beamer, LaTeX Warning: Command \InputIfFileExists has changed

Tags: beamer, warnings

It seems that problem with \InputIfFileExists in beamer still exist. Compiling:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}

some text $\mathbf{A}$.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

gives after two compilations with XeLaTeX compilation (recent MikTeX) I get warning (compilation with pdfLaTeX engine gives beside this warnings four other, also result is different);

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \InputIfFileExists  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.
```

I tested with recent MikTeX. List of files used in above MWE is:

```
 *File List*
  beamer.cls    2020/07/22 v3.59 A class for typesetting presentations
beamerbasemodes.sty    
etoolbox.sty    2020/08/24 v2.5j e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
beamerbasedecode.sty    
   ifpdf.sty    2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
beamerbaseoptions.sty    
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
geometry.cfg
  size11.clo    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
graphicx.sty    2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
   xetex.def    2020/08/26 v5.0i Graphics/color driver for xetex
  pgfsys.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
  pgfrcs.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
pgfrcs.code.tex
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
atbegshi.sty    2019/12/05 v1.19 At begin shipout hook (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.24 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
hyperref.sty    2020-05-15 v7.00e Hypertext links for LaTeX
pdftexcmds.sty    2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2019/11/29 v3.13 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  bitset.sty    2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  hxetex.def    2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref driver for XeTeX
   puenc.def    2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
stringenc.sty    2019/11/29 v1.12 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
atveryend.sty    2019-12-11 v1.11 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
se-ascii-print.def    2019/11/29 v1.12 stringenc: Printable ASCII characters
beamerbaserequires.sty    
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    
beamerbasefont.sty    
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
sansmathaccent.sty    2020/01/31
scrlfile.sty    2018/12/30 v3.26a KOMA-Script package (loading files)
beamerbasetranslator.sty    
translator.sty    2020-08-03 v1.12c Easy translation of strings in LaTeX
beamerbasemisc.sty    
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    
beamerbasetitle.sty    
beamerbasesection.sty    
beamerbaseframe.sty    
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    
beamerbaseframesize.sty    
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    
beamerbasecolor.sty    
beamerbasenotes.sty    
beamerbasetoc.sty    
beamerbasetemplates.sty    
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    
beamerbaseboxes.sty    
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    
enumerate.sty    2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    
beamerbasetheorems.sty    
 amsmath.sty    2020/01/20 v2.17e AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2020/05/29 v2.20.6
beamerbasethemes.sty    
beamerthemedefault.sty    
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    
l3backend-xetex.def    2020-09-01 L3 backend support: XeTeX
  ts1cmr.fd    2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
 nameref.sty    2019/09/16 v2.46 Cross-referencing by name of section
refcount.sty    2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
gettitlestring.sty    2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
beamer-test.out
beamer-test.out
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-months-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict    
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
 ***********

Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 10.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `beamer-test.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
 )
```

Warning is not critical but is a bit annoying. Do I miss something in my MWE? I read answers and comments on this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512189/problem-with-chemmacros-beamer-and-filehook-scrlfile-sty), so I wonder if something new has happened in the meantime?

Comment: you have an outdated scrlfile.sty, the newest version is from 2020/07.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thank you for info. I suspect that it is part of koma-script bundle, and very strange, MikTeX console indicate that I  haven't installed it ... After installing it now all works! Are you willing to write an answer?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved by installing recent version of the `koma-script` bundle as was suggested @Ulrike Fischerin in the her comment.